# Image File Face Detection in Folder (using os.walk)

Tags: python, opencv, os.walk

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('c:\images'):
    for fname in files:
        img = cv2.imread(fname)
        cv2.resize(img, None, fx=0.4, fy=0.3, interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
        eyes = eye_cascade.detectMultiScale(img, 1.1, 5)
        faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(img, 1.2, 5)
        noses = nose_cascade.detectMultiScale(img, 1.1, 5)
        mouths = mouth_cascade.detectMultiScale(img, 1.1, 5)
```

has error

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (ssize.area() > 0) in cv::resize, file ..\..\..\..\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\imgwarp.cpp, line 1968
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/FaceDetWeightSave.py", line 19, in <module>
    cv2.resize(img, None, fx=0.4, fy=0.3, interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
cv2.error: ..\..\..\..\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\imgwarp.cpp:1968: error: (-215) ssize.area() > 0 in function cv::resize
```

I think that this error is from `os.walk(for root, dirs, files <- this)`. How can I detect files?

Comment: yea, your image seems to be empty. are there subdirs (e.g. for each person) ?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't know about 'subdir' <- is it sub-directory?

Comment: yes, i meant like c:/images/person1/img_003.png

Comment: yes. C:/opencv_myname/images/asdf.jpg

Comment: Solved. cause of sub-directory... and other files like .txt, .xml,.....,etc

Answer (score 0):

you need to prepend the dir-name to the image-name, else your script won't find the image:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('c:\images'):
    for fname in files: # fname is the plain filename only
        src = os.path.join(root, fname) # this is the absolute path to the image
        img = cv2.imread(src)
        ...
```

Comment: I think you meant prepend rather than append.